# Rails add order to scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app with a working scope based on a field in an associated model:

```
scope :maintenance, -> { joins(:costcat).where(costcats: { maintenance: true }) }
```

I would like the results to be ordered by `costcats.position`.

I tried these:

```
scope :maintenance, -> { joins(:costcat).where(costcats: { maintenance: true }).order(costcats.position ASC) }
scope :maintenance, -> { joins(:costcat).where(costcats: { maintenance: true }) }, :order => "costcats.position ASC"
```

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

With the suggested answers, I'm getting the following SQL:

```
SELECT "costestimates".* FROM "costestimates" INNER JOIN "costcats" ON "costcats"."id" = "costestimates"."costcat_id" WHERE "costestimates"."costproject_id" = 1 AND "costcats"."maintenance" = 't' ORDER BY id ASC, position ASC
```

It would work if the `id ASC` wasn't in the ORDER

UDDATE2

My bad, I had to remove the default scope order in `costestimates`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scope :maintenance, 
      ->{ joins(:costcat).where(costcats: { maintenance: true }).order("costcats.position")}
```

Comment: A little description to your answer would be nicer!

Comment: BTW, ilan skipped ASC because that's the default. If you wanted to use descending order, you'd add DESC inside the string: `joins(:costcat).where(costcats: { maintenance: true }).order("costcats.position DESC")`

Answer (score 1):

I like using [`#merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) because it makes the query look cleaner

```
scope :maintenance, ->{ joins(:costcat)
                         .merge(
                           Costcat.where(maintenance: true).order(:position)
                         )
                       }
```

**PS:** multiline is only for readability

Comment: neat! does this trigger the exact same query?

Comment: @caesarsol: yes, I think `#merge` for some reason is an under-used method though I think it's very neat, it gives you access to the other model's scopes, for example you could say `.merge(Costcat.under_maintenance.order_by_position)` without the need of knowing the name of the fields and their values, I've wrote about that scopes part in a post over here http://blog.abushady.com/2015/03/02/using-active-records-merge-to-separate-concerns.html, would be nice if you could take a look and tell me what you think.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work for seeing the records in the sort order? `<%= @costproject.costestimates.maintenance.each do |costestimate| %>`

Comment: @Reddirt I don't understand, is this the same question or something else?

Comment: @Mohammad AbuShady - it's the same question - but, it wasn't working until I removed the default scope order for `costestimate` - now it's working.

Comment: @Reddirt o yea default scopes are evil, if you still need the default scope you can use `unscoped`, so `CostProject.unscoped.where(...)` this will remove the default scope conditions in this query.